# Small step in proving Hilbert's (Weak) Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading up on a proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz which uses the Artin-Tate lemma. I followed all of it except for one step, which is probably quite elementary, but my brain may be too fried from the rest of the proof to find the logic.

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $I$ be a maximal ideal of
>   the polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. After much proof, we have that
>   $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I=k$. Then for each $x_i$, there
>   exists $a_i\in k$ such that $x_i-a_i\in I$.

(Finishing the proof from here, $I$ must contain the ideal $(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$, and that ideal is maximal, so $I$ is exactly that.) What's the reason for why such an $a_i$ exists? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $f: k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to k$. The image of each $x_i$ is some element in $k$, call it $b_i$. Then since $f$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, we have that $f(x_i-b_i)=f(x_i)-f(b_i)=b_i-b_i=0$, or that $x_i-b_i\in I$, and thus $b_i$ is the desired $a_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ to save space. Here is the argument in (too much) detail: there is a canonical injection $f\colon k \to A$, and after much effort we show that the composition of this embedding and the quotient map $g\colon A \to A/I$ is an isomorphism. So for each $i$ there is a unique $a_i \in k$ such that $g(f(a_i)) = g(x_i)$. Is the result clear now?

Comment: Maybe the important thing to note is that _everything is being treated as a $k$-algebra_, and so $A/I$ is not just isomorphic to $k$ via some relatively arbitrary ring homomorphism: there's a canonical copy of $k$ inside of it and the proof shows that this is in fact all of $A/I$.

Comment: Ah, I got it. If I know that $A/I=k$ , then I can just consider the commutative diagram $f:k\to A, g:A\to A/I, h: A/I\to k$ where $f$ is injective, $g$ surjective, and $h$ isomorphic. Then $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism. Hence, the result follows. Thanks!